# Angular is undefined in angular-animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-debugger

I'm building an angular application, I've got a couple of modules with services and controllers all of which are functioning correctly.
I've just added angular-animate to my list of scripts, which are loaded from a cshtml file before my app.js (slightly redacted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angularjs/angular.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/ui-router/angular-ui-router.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

When angular-animate runs through I get an error saying "noop cannot be found on undefined", see the top of angular-animate:

```js
(function(window, angular, undefined) {'use strict';

var noop        = angular.noop;
var extend      = angular.extend;
var jqLite      = angular.element;
var forEach     = angular.forEach;
```

It seems the 'angular' being passed in is null. But angular-cookies has an identical header at the top and a non-null angular is passed in. All the files are valid and I'm running versions which match my angular version.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you place angular-animate before ui-router? Or before angular-cookies?

Comment: Are you passing in angular when you call your wrapper function?

Comment: it is cause 'defer' attribute - u rly need it? Then add it to animate too. But usually u dont need it in angular actually.

Comment: I think you're right @petr, it's probably because of the defer tag on the other scripts. Write that as an answer and I'll confirm it in the morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pryt pointed out in a comment, the problem was that the other script tags had a defer whereas the new one did not.
This caused angular-animate to run before angular had loaded.